# Составление алгоритма для выбора определённых данных из массива

Tags: python

Нужен алгоритм подсчета числа элементов, равных максимальному, в числовом массиве из 30 элементов. Что не так?

```
a = []
n = 30
k = 0
m = 0
for i in range(0, n+1):
    a.append(n)
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if a[i-1] > a[i]:
         a[i-1],a[i] = a[i], a[i-1]
         m = a[n+1]
for i in range(0,n):
    if m == a[i]:
        k +=1
print(k)
```

Comment: Опишите на русском и исправьте заголовок. По названию должна быть понятна задача

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, n+1):
    a.append(n)
```

У вас массив состоит только из элементов, равных `n`.

```
k = 1
max = a[0]
for i in range(1, n+1):
    if a[i] > max:
        max = a[i]
        k = 1
    elif a[i] == max:
        k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> алгоритм подсчета числа элементов, равных максимальному, в числовом массиве `a`

```
print(a.count(max(a)))
```